# Declaration of ReplaceProcessor::process($tokenList) must be compatible with InsertProcessor::process($tokenList, $token_category = 'INSERT')

Tags: php, sql-parser

I'm using [PHP SQL Parser](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-sql-parser/). Working fine last few months I upgrade PHP 7.2

Then I got the error like.

```
> Declaration of ReplaceProcessor::process($tokenList) must be
> compatible with InsertProcessor::process($tokenList, $token_category =
> 'INSERT')
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Got the Solution!

Replace the following class definition in "server/PHPSqlParser/processors/ReplaceProcessor.php"

Line 42

```
class ReplaceProcessor extends InsertProcessor {

    public function process($tokenList, $token_category = 'REPLACE') {
        return parent::process($tokenList, $token_category);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to add the $isUpdate parameter the DuplicateProcessor class in the same manner though. Seems like a pretty abandoned project altogether. But hopefully it'll come in handy during migration efforts.